# Making an array of objects from json using jq

Tags: bash, jq

```
[
  {
    "username": "new",
    "attributes": [
      {
        "name": "attr1",
        "value": "value1"
      },
      {
        "name": "attr2",
        "value": "value2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "username": "new2",
    "attributes": [
      {
        "name": "attr2",
        "value": "value3"
      },
      {
        "name": "attr1",
        "value": "value4"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I have a json as above. From this json, I would like to get the following:

```
[
  {
    "username": "new",
    "value": "value1"
  },
  {
    "username": "new2",
    "value": "value4"
  }
]
```

The value I want to have in this object is the value for attribute named attr1. How I can achieve this with jq?

Edit: Fixed errors in the qn. I have tried

```
echo $USERS | jq ['.[] | {username:username, value: jq '.attributes[]  | select(.name == "attr1") | .value'}'];
```

where $USERS contains the json data

Comment: The shown expected output is inconsistent with the stated requirements. Please fix and also show at least one attempt you’ve made to solve the problem. As they say, SO is not a free programming service.

Comment: Why is Value lowercased?

Comment: Should `value4` be `value3`?

Comment: if `attr1` is always present you can use `map({ username, value: .attributes | map(select(.name == "attr1"))[0].value })`

Comment: @nanoticket - What if attr1 does not occur in the array, or occurs more than once?

Comment: attr1 is not always present. It won't occur more than once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 map({ username,
       value: first(.attributes[]
                    | select(.name == "attr1")
                    | .value) })
```

Comment: @dan1st - It's just four lines of very straightforward code, so there's really nothing more to be said other than perhaps: please check the jq tutorial if you're unfamiliar with jq, and please check the jq manual if you're unfamiliar with `map` or `select`.